# Is it possible to render to texture's mipmap level 1 while sampling from level 0? (opengl, texture 2d)

Tags: opengl, sampling, render-to-texture, mipmaps, downsampling

Is it possible to render to one of RenderTexture's mipmap level while sampling from other levels?

The situation is i want to downscale a texture 4 times using shader, i could put all these intermediate results together on a big texture (at level 0, no mip levels) but i don't know how to handle texture cell edges (GL_CLAMP, GL_REPEAT), another way would be to create 4 FBOs but it's not as convenient as using same texture different mipmap levels.

what do you say?

thank you.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Framebuffer_objects

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. I've settled on using multiple-FBOs.

Comment: If a texture is attached to a framebuffer object, and you also want to read from the texture, you must use the texture mipmap range specifiers to make it actively impossible to access any mipmap levels that are attached.